# Spring batch JdbcPaginingItemReader is not being thread-safe between multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

My ThreadPoolTaskExecutor's corePoolSize is 5 and in JdbcPaginingItemReader bean config I have set saveState to false (per documentation it should be set to false if used in a multi-threaded env) and my table have a primary key, which I am using in sortKey attribute of queryProvider yet when task-executor spawns all five threads simultaneously they all are trying to read the data, startAfterValues of JdbcPaginingItemReader is getting messed up. Reader call from each thread is reading the duplicate rows due to the fact that startAfterValues is not thread safe.

How do I overcome this?

Here are my config info.

```
<job id="myJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" incrementer="jobIncrementer">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet task-executor="myTaskExecutor">
            <chunk reader="myReader" writer="myWriter" commit-interval="1000" />
            <transaction-attributes isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
            <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT ID, NAME"/>
            <property name="fromClause" value="FROM EMPLOYEE" />
            <property name="whereClause" value="where 1=1" />
            <property name="sortKey" value="ID"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
    <property name="fetchSize" value="1000"/>
    <property name="saveState" value="false"/>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com...MyRowMapper"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myWriter" class="com...MyItemWriter" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <constructor-arg name="namedParamJdbcTemplate" ref="namedParamJdbcTemplate" />
    <constructor-arg name="endUserID" value="123" />
</bean>

<bean id="myTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you share your config? Is your reader step-scoped?

Comment: Yes Mahmoud. My reader step is step scoped. Let me try to add more details to my original post

Comment: The more I dig in, JdbcPagingItemReader creates firstPageSql as "WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000" and remainingPagesSql as "WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000 AND ((ID > ?))" and the ID (primary key) that dynamically getting passed in, is getting messed up, reading duplicate data. Not sure how I can go about this situation.

Comment: I hope `where 1=1` is there just for illustration purpose, otherwise it is not surprising that all threads are reading the same data. I was not able to reproduce the is issue, see this repo: https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-sandbox/tree/master/so60459764 with similar setup. If you can provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue, I can take a look.